# Algorithm for returning a matrix that is the sum of the previous matrix

Tags: algorithms

I had an interview question that asked me a rather simple question:

> Design a function that takes in a matrix and indices *i* and *j*. The function should return the sum of all numbers in the matrix along $i$ and $j$, but not after $i,j$.

So, if you had a matrix $$A = [[1, 2, 3] \\
                              \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space [4, 5, 6]\\
         \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space                     [7, 8, 9]]$$

And indices $i = 1, j = 1$, you would need to return $2+5+4=11$. If you had $i=2,j=1$, then you would need to return $2+5+8+7 = 22$. If you had $i=2,j=2$, you would be returning $3+6+9+8+7=33$. And so on.

Cool, easy enough:

```
def get_add(matrix, i, j):
    sum1 = 0
    for a in range(i + 1):
        print "i ", a, matrix[a][j]
        sum1 += matrix[a][j]

    sum2 = 0
    for a in range(j):
        print "j ", a, matrix[i][a]
        sum2 += matrix[i][a]

    return sum1 + sum2
```

But I had an interesting follow-up question. The interviewer said, "Okay, now I want you to design a function that will construct another matrix $B$ with $B_{i,j}$ equal to the output of your function `get_add(A, i, j)`.

Now, the question was proposed in a way that was saying, "Is there a more efficient way of creating this matrix B?" Using get_add to make this matrix would be, what, $O(n^3)$ or something? Is there a better solution? I couldn't really come up with something, though I am sure there must be something better.

Thank you

Comment: One approach is to consider a simpler problem first: What if I wanted to compute a matrix $B_1$ whose $(i,j)$-th entry would be the sum of all elements "along" $j$ but not beyond $(i,j)$ (i.e. the values computed by your Python function if we removed the second loop). Can you see how to compute this simper matrix in $O(n^2)$ (hint: $a+b+c+d=(a+b+c)+d$).